# Where is the error in my Java code to connect to a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql

I am currently programming a Plugin for Minecraft (Spigot). For this Plugin, I need to connect to a MySQL database.

But, within the logs, there is an error in line 35.

[line 35]: `prop.setProperty("requireSSL", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQl.ssl"));`

thats my DataBaseManager class:

```
package de._dagobert_duck.pbp.SQL;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;
import de._dagobert_duck.pbp.PiggyBankPlus;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class DataBaseManagerSQL
{
    private Connection connection;
    private static final PiggyBankPlus pbp = PiggyBankPlus.getMain();
    
    public DataBaseManagerSQL() {
        this.connection = null;
        this.connectToDataBase();
        this.setupDatabase();
    }
    
    private void connectToDataBase() {
        pbp.getLogger().info("Connecting to database ...");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("user", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.username"));
            prop.setProperty("password", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.password"));
            prop.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
            prop.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate", "false");
            /*line35*/prop.setProperty("useSSL", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.ssl"));
            prop.setProperty("requireSSL", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQl.ssl"));
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.host") + ":" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.port") + "/" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.dataBaseName"), prop);
            pbp.getLogger().info("Connected to MySQL database successfully. :D");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            pbp.getLogger().severe("Unable to locate the drivers for MySQL. Err: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        catch (SQLException f) {
            pbp.getLogger().severe("Unable to connect to MySQL. Err: " + f.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }
    

    public boolean setupDatabase() {
        PreparedStatement query = null;
        label71: {
            try {
                final String data = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.tableName` (id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, player_uuid varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, player_name varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, money double(30, 2) NOT NULL, last_seen varchar(30) NOT NULL, sync_complete varchar(5) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)); ");
                query = this.connection.prepareStatement(data);
                query.execute();
                break label71;
            } catch (SQLException g) {
                g.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    if (query != null) {
                        query.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception h) {
                    h.printStackTrace();
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (query != null) {
                        query.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception h2) {
                    h2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        this.updateTables();
        return true;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        this.checkConnection();
        return this.connection;
    }
    
    public boolean checkConnection() {
        try {
            if (this.connection == null) {
                pbp.getLogger().warning("Connection failed! Trying to reconnect ...");
                return this.reConnect();
            }
            else if (!this.connection.isValid(3)) {
                pbp.getLogger().warning("Connection to database is failed or terminated! Trying to reconnect ... ");
                return this.reConnect();
            }
            else if (this.connection.isClosed()) {
                pbp.getLogger().warning("[PiggyBankPlus] Connection to database is closed! Trying to reconnect ...");
                return this.reConnect();
            }
            else
            {return true;}
        }
        catch (Exception i) {
            pbp.getLogger().warning("[PiggyBankPlus] Could not reconnect to Database!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean reConnect() {
        try {
            long start = 0L;
            long end = 0L;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            final Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("user", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.username"));
            prop.setProperty("password", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.password"));
            prop.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
            prop.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate", "false");
            prop.setProperty("useSSL", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.ssl"));
            prop.setProperty("requireSSL", pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.ssl"));
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.host") + ":" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.port") + "/" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.dataBaseName"), prop);
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long time = end - start;
            pbp.getLogger().info(" successfully reconnected to MySQL server. Time: " + time + " ms");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception j) {
            pbp.getLogger().warning("[PiggyBankPlus] Reconnection to MySQL failed! Err: " + j.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean closeDatabase() {
        try {
            this.connection.close();
            this.connection = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (SQLException k) {
            k.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    private void updateTables() {
        if (this.connection != null) {
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = null;
            ResultSet rs1 = null;
            ResultSet rs2 = null;
            ResultSet rs3 = null;
            PreparedStatement query1 = null;
            PreparedStatement query2 = null;
            PreparedStatement query3 = null;
            try {
                dbmd = this.connection.getMetaData();
                rs1 = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.tableName"), "sync_complete");
                if (!rs1.next()) {
                    final String data = "ALTER TABLE `" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.tableName") + "` ADD sync_complete varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true';";
                    query1 = this.connection.prepareStatement(data);
                    query1.execute();
                }
                rs2 = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.tableName"), "player_name");
                if (!rs2.next()) {
                    final String data = "ALTER TABLE `" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.tableName") + "` ADD player_name varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true';";
                    query2 = this.connection.prepareStatement(data);
                    query2.execute();
                }
                rs3 = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.tableName"), "last_seen");
                if (!rs3.next()) {
                    final String data = "ALTER TABLE `" + pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.tableName") + "` ADD last_seen varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true';";
                    query3 = this.connection.prepareStatement(data);
                    query3.execute();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception l) {
                pbp.getLogger().warning(" Error while updating inventory table! Err: " + l.getMessage());
                l.printStackTrace();

            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (query1 != null) {
                        query1.close();
                    }
                    if (query2 != null) {
                        query2.close();
                    }
                    if (query3 != null) {
                        query3.close();
                    }
                    if (rs1 != null) {
                        rs1.close();
                    }
                    if (rs2 != null) {
                        rs2.close();
                    }
                    if (rs3 != null) {
                        rs3.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception i) {
                    i.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to find the error?

Thank you,

Scrooge McDuck

Comment: `But, within the logs, there is an error in line 35.` Which error?

Comment: Can you also share the source code of the PiggyBankPlus to understand what getConfigManager actually returns? But to quickly fix the problem, just replace `pbp.getConfigManager().getString("MySQL.ssl")` with `true` or `false` depending on your database connection needs.

Comment: @tkausl: Wait a moment.

Comment: @Alexander: pbp.getConfigManager().getString(String key) searches in the config (YAML) for that key and returns it's value. key : value. But isn't it the same if I get a "true" or "false" String from the config? But thank you for your answer.